# To move the column values to next row in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the below excel sheet i have 5 columns Empname,Empsalary,age,contactno,mobileno.Now i want to move the value of the mobile no to contactno.Pls help me to do this.

```
EmpName |Empsalary |age | contactno |mobile no|
xx         250       24   564548      899898   
yy         963       19   98656       856559
Expected Result
EmpName |Empsalary |age | contactno 
xx         250       24   564548      
xx         250       24   899898 
yy         963       19   98656       
yy         963       19   856559
```

Comment: you may use vba i.e .xlsm file? If so, try some code and post here.

Answer (score 0):

The result can be easily obtained by copying and pasting all values in EmpName, Empsalary and age columns after the last one and then copy mobile no values and paste them accordingly under contactno column. You can then reorder the cells as you like to have same result you showed here.

This is of course a "quick and dirty" solution that requires no VBA code in your Excel file.